# matrix derivative in R

Tags: r, matrix, symbolic-math, calculus

I would like to do symbolic computation for the derivative of a matrix with respect to a vector in R. Is there any recommendation of the R package I can use?

I tried packages like deriv, rSymPy, and calculus. But none seemed to work for the purpose.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The **cOde** package can be useful.

```r
library(cOde)

charvec <- c(f1 = "sin(x)", f2 = "cos(x)", f3 = "atan(y/x)", f4 = "tan(x+y)")

j_code <- cOde::jacobianSymb(f = charvec, variables = c("x", "y"))

print(j_code)
#              f1.x                   f2.x                   f3.x                   f4.x 
#          "cos(x)"              "-sin(x)" "-(y/x^2/(1+(y/x)^2))"         "1/cos(x+y)^2" 
#              f1.y                   f2.y                   f3.y                   f4.y 
#               "0"                    "0"      "1/x/(1+(y/x)^2)"         "1/cos(x+y)^2"
```

See [this document](https://ms.mcmaster.ca/%7Ebolker/misc/jacobian.html).